# Losing chamadorea elegans stalks

Tags: plant-health

[image]

So I’ve lost about two of these little stalks over the pas couple of weeks and I’m not sure what the problem is. They are sitting in a place a couple meters from a window but there is enough sunlight to make some sort of shadow behind the plants. (Indirect sunlight) they certainly don’t get overwatered as I don’t water them everyday. Could I be underwatering the plants? I water them a couple times a week but I may be waiting for the soil to be too dry before I water it. Could this be an underwatering problem?[image][image]

Comment: They are "palm trees," but their natural environment is a rain forest, not a desert. They like high humidity and indirect light. Try misting the leaves regularly as well as watering.

Comment: Would be good to see a picture of the whole plant as well if possible, including the pot so we can get an idea of overall size of both. Any signs of infestation by anything on the leaves or stems? When you water, how much water do you give it (this is why I'd like to see a photo of the whole plant and pot, to judge how much water you're giving in relation to the pot/plant size)

Comment: Hi and thanks so much for responding. I added two more pictures to the original post so you guys can get a better idea of where the plant is (some meters away from a south face window) and also the plant’s pot. I mist my plants about 5/7 days of the week but sometimes it is less or more depending on how much I remember. I never mist of course the plant is already wet I just do so to increase humidity some. I water her when she gets a little dry but not completely and water until water runs down the bottom and then stop and poor remaining water out so she isn’t standing in water

Comment: No signs of infestation at all. I’m losing a couple of the stalks but the “established” bigger stalks look happy, healthy, no bugs I can see